# Execute Shell Command, and read it's output in Chrome Packaged Apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I need to develop a Chrome Packaged App that will work as a UI for a console application.

For this I need to find a way to be able to execute that console application inside my Packaged App and read it's outputs.

This is a simple task to do in another platforms such as .NET (which I use nowadays).

I've googled everywhere and searched here on Stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find anything related.

The only interoperability I found is NPAPI, (which is about to be discontinuead). So...
Does anyone have a knowledge about this and could give an example or documentarion on how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a feature as part of Chrome extensions that might suit you needs called native messaging.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging-client

Comment: I'm pretty sure Native Client won't work, as it's very restricted in the system calls it can execute.

Comment: Native Messaging is not the same as Native Client. Native Messaging communicates with a completely separate process, outside of Chrome's sandbox. I've used native messaging to do basically what the OP is asking for!